# Django: How to create form with ForeignKey field (input as CharField)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have created two models Article and Author as this:

**model.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 5000)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author_intro = models.TextField(max_length = 3000)
```

And I am trying to create a form that lets user input Article information *(including title, content, author only). So that whenever user input an author, that input data is stored in both `author` (in Article model) and `author_name` (in Author model). Is this possible to do? I can not seem to get it working. Here's what I tried:

**form.py:**

```
class articleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    author = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title']          
        widgets = {
        'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 75, 'rows': 50})}


class authorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['author_name']
```

**views.py:**

```
def compose_article(request):

    form_article = articleForm(request.POST or None)
    if form_article.is_valid():
        instance = form_article.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()

    context = {
        "ArtileForm":form_article,
    }
    return render(request,"Upload.html",context)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you investigated formsets?

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the author name input as a char field and handle getting or creating the author manually.
You also need to set `unique=True` on `author_name`. Try a form like this:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'author', 'content']
        widgets = {
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 75, 'rows': 50}),
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        author, created = Author.objects.get_or_create(
            author_name=self.cleaned_data['author'],
            defaults={'author_intro': ''}
        )
        self.cleaned_data['author'] = author.id
        return super(ArticleForm, self).save(commit)
```

And a view like this:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class ArticleFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = ArticleForm
    template_name = 'Upload.html'

    # You can skip this method if you change "ArtileForm" to "form"
    # in your template.
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        cd = super(ArticleFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cd['ArtileForm'] = cd['form']
        return cd
compose_article = ArticleFormView.as_view()
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to move the code from the save to clean

```
def clean(self):
        group, created = Ideas_Group.objects.get_or_create(
                    category_text=self.cleaned_data.get('group'))
        self.cleaned_data['group'] = group
        return super(IdeasForm, self).clean()
```

and then in the views.py was just a regular process

```
def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IdeasForm(request.POST)                                                                 
        if form.is_valid():
            ideapost = form.save(commit=False)                                       
            ideapost.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just arrived here about a similar problem. Starting with your code, in my case, I've added "__id".

```
class articleForm(forms.ModelForm):

     author__id = forms.IntegerField(...
```

Printing this part of the form. (27 is the id of my testcase.)

```
<tr><th><label for="id_author">Author:</label></th><td><select name="author" required id="id_author">
   <option value="">---------</option>

   <option value="27" selected>Author</option>

 </select></td></tr>
```